# Regular expression match only the first string per line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to achieve this:

given these lines:

```
<script src="/vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/vendor/underscore/underscore.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I would like to match:

```
/vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js
/vendor/underscore/underscore.js
```

but I've achieved only this result.

```
"/vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js" "utf-8"
"/vendor/underscore/underscore.js" "utf-8"
```

Using this pattern :

```
/".+?"/gm
```

[Here](http://www.regexr.com/3aie9) you can try it live, and watch my result.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `/src="([^"]+)"/gm` and then get first matching group for each match.

For example:

```
s = '<script src="/vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js" charset="utf-8"></script>';
(/src="([^"]+)"/gm).exec(s)[1];
```

returns:

```
/vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js
```

Answer (score 0):

What about checking for a backslash in the beginning, short and simple

```
"\/.+?"
```